# Shaded Relief Map to Contours

Tags: contour, shaded-relief

Is there a way to create contour map from a given shaded relief map?

Comment: There could be a way but not reliably and certainly not without a *great* deal of effort, reverse engineering relief shade to elevation and thence to contours.. you might be better served downloading SRTM DEM and generating contours from that *but* don't expect a contour interval of less than 10 metres over 1 arcsecond and 30 metres over 3 arcsecond areas.

Comment: IF I have the SRTM DEM data, how can I extract the contour data? Can ArcGIS be used?

Comment: With ArcGIS you will need 3d analyst or spatial analyst extension using the tool Contour (3d) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q900000021000000 or Contour (sa) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000ts000000 if you don't have either spatial or 3d analyst you can use GDAL_Contour http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html. The GDAL contours are a little more *engineering* than Esri contours; you can smooth the GDAL contours by resampling with GDALWarp with cubic to half the cell size.